# Changing "+" in textarea to <input type='checkbox'>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to convert all the `+` sign in the textarea field where the user types and parse that `+` sign and the text after it until the newline character into an HTML `input checkbox`.
For example, if the user, in the `textarea`, types:

```
+ Feed the kittens
+ Call the doctor
+ Go buy grocery
```

I want to parse it to something like:

```
<input type="checkbox"><label>Feed the kittens</label>
<input type="checkbox"><label>Call the doctor</label>
<input type="checkbox"><label>Go buy grocery</label>
```

I need to return this as a `string` with the `HTML` in it.

I created a `function` called `listNote(note)` that takes in `note` which is the text in the `textarea`. How should I go about writing this?

Comment: how are you planning on preventing users from adding multiple `+` on each line? do you have the option to use an alternate solution than a `textarea` for the user to input their data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may refer below code for an idea:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#parseButton").click(function() {
    var str = $("#mytext").val(); //get the text entered by user

    var allLabels = str.split("+"); //split the text assuming that user will be writing data in required fashion

    allLabels.shift(); //skip the 0th index of array which will be blank

    var htmlString = "";
    //iterate over all the tasks one by one to form html string
    $.each(allLabels, function(index, value) {

      htmlString += '<input type="checkbox"><label>' + value + '</label>';
    });

    //append the html to div
    $("#myHtml").html(htmlString);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="mytext" rows="4" cols="50">
  + Feed the kittens 
  + Call the doctor 
  + Go buy grocery</textarea>
<button id="parseButton">Parse</button>

</br>
</br>
Output:
<div id="myHtml"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do :

- split the `textarea` content into separate notes, either splitting over `+` (but you need to ignore the first item of the array) or linefeed (but then you can't have multilines notes)
- remove the leading `+`  (a simple substring is enough)
- add the tag opening and closing (string concatenation)

Hope it gets you started !

Answer (score 0):

Try with simple [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) and [ArrayMap](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)

```js
function change(){
  var final="";
var res =$('textarea').val().split("+");
  res.map(function(a){
    if(a != ""){
    final += '<input type="checkbox"><label>'+a+'</label>';
    }
  })
  console.log(final)

 $('body').append(final)
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea  cols="20" rows="4" >+ Feed the kittens
+ Call the doctor
+ Go buy grocery </textarea>
<button onclick="change()">click</button>
```